# Laravel routing & filters

Tags: laravel, filter, laravel-routing

I want to build fancy `url` in my site with these `url` patterns:

- `http://domain.com/specialization/eye`
- `http://domain.com/clinic-dr-house`
- `http://domain.com/faq`

The first `url` has a simple route pattern:

```
Route::get('/specialization/{slug}', 'FrontController@specialization');
```

The second and the third `url` refers to two different controller actions:

- `SiteController@clinic`
- `SiteController@page`

I try with this filter:

```
Route::filter('/{slug}',function()
{
    if(Clinic::where('slug',$slug)->count() == 1)
        Route::get('/{slug}','FrontController@clinic');

    if(Page::where('slug',$slug)->count() == 1)
        Route::get('/{slug}','FrontController@page');
});
```

And I have an Exception... there is a less painful method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare a filter you should use a filter a static name, for example:

```
Route::filter('filtername',function()
{
    // ...
});
```

Then you may use this filter in your routes like this way:

```
Route::get('/specialization/{slug}', array('before' => 'filtername', 'uses' => 'FrontController@specialization'));
```

So, whenever you use `http://domain.com/specialization/eye` the filter attached to this route will be executed before the route is dispatched. Read more on [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters).

**Update:** For second and third routes you may check the route parameter in thew filter and do different things depending on the parameter. Also, you may use one method for both urls, technically both urls are identical to one route so use one route and depending on the param, do different things, for example you have following `url`s:

```
http://domain.com/clinic-dr-house
http://domain.com/faq
```

Use a single route for both url, for example, use:

```
Route::get('/{param}', 'FrontController@common');
```

Create `common` method in your `FrontController` like this:

```
public function common($param)
{
    // Check the param, if param is clinic-dr-house
    // the do something or do something else for faq
    // or you may use redirect as well
}
```

Comment: Ok, but your answer not respond to my problem: the last two urls, how i can manage the difference of case that i have?

Comment: You don't need two different methods for same route signature, instead you may catch all (same) routes in single route and do different things from the method.

Comment: Ok, i think there was "a way" to do this into the routes and/or use the filters. 
I'm coming from Codeigniter, when in CI i use a "selector" function that can recognize the SLUG and call the correct Controller Method; so i think i'm going to do the same with Laravel.

Thanks a lot!